# Datagrid copy while preserving string structure

Tags: wpf, string, copy, format

I have a datagrid in which I have certain columns for which I've modified their string format such as this, which takes in a UINT32 number and outputs its hex format.

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=getStart, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='{}{0:x4}'}" Header="Starting Address"  Width="13*"/>
```

When I copy a row however, I get the UINT number again instead of the hex, as I would have liked. Is there a way to preserve the string format? I've looked into CopyingRowClipboardContent but I'm not quite sure how to use this event handler properly. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try do something like that:

1) Add property getStartS type of string to your class and in getter you can format your string.

```
 public class Foo
    {
        public int getStart { get; set; }

        public string getStartS { get { return string.Format("{0:x4}", getStart); } }
    }
```

2) In DataGrid column you can bind to getStartS property and it'll work properly!

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=getStartS}" 
                                    Header="Starting Address"                                    
                                    />
```

**Or you can try second solution:**

DataGrid column:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=getStart, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='{}{0:x4}'}" 
                                    Header="Starting Address"
                                    CopyingCellClipboardContent="DataGridTextColumn_CopyingCellClipboardContent"
                                    />
```

Event handler:

```
 private void DataGridTextColumn_CopyingCellClipboardContent(object sender, DataGridCellClipboardEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column.ClipboardContentBinding != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Column.ClipboardContentBinding.StringFormat))
            {
                e.Content = string.Format(e.Column.ClipboardContentBinding.StringFormat, e.Content);
            }
        }
```